# Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 Disk Size Consumption

Tags: ubuntu, ext4

I have installed Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 as a VM guest under HyperV (dynamically expanding vhdx). All seems to be going pretty well.

However, I noticed that the HyperV disk size had ballooned to around 40GB, so when I investigated the Ubuntu VM, gparted announced that it is indeed consuming 38.17GB. Which was really weird since it's a plain vanilla install (no update packages yet). the bundled disk usage analyzer mentioned that outside of the inaccessible folder (/etc/cups/ssl), everything seems to be accounted for and it came up with 3.7GB.

in searching for answers, I stumbled across an article (http://dillidba.blogspot.ca/2015/10/remove-journal-from-ext4-for-disk-io.html) which allowed me to disable the ext4 journal, which I promptly did after installation. I also verified that the disk does not have the has_journal feature enabled. However, the disk consumption still stayed high.

I have no idea where the 35GB went, and what files are occupying it, and was hoping someone can help me clear this space up.

please note that this is a duplicate from stackoverflow as I was given a suggestion to post here instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging into your Ubuntu installation and running Gnome Disk Usage Analyzer(`baobab`, if run from the command line). That'll provide a simple, graphical way of seeing how much space is used up and what files are using it. If baobab says that files are using much less than 40gb, you might want to try shrinking your root filesystem. Otherwise, delete whatever it is that's taking up all of the space(after ensuring that it isn't important)

This page provides a(very risky) way to shrink your root filesystem while logged into your machine:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226872/how-to-shrink-root-filesystem-without-booting-a-livecd

If you can access your virtual disk from another linux installation(or live boot disk), try using resize2fs to shrink while the root filesystem is not mounted.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/resize2fs.8.html

Comment: thanks @Anton Liakhovitch. it would appear that the way Ubuntu 16.04 is using the disk causes Hyper-V to want to keep expanding it. I can't quite place my finger on it, so I just reset the partition to a smaller size (127Gb instead of 2TB). the disk did eventually fill up to 127GB, but baobab reports only 20GB, so I guess that means technically speaking I'm not running out of disk.